# Codeigniter: highlighting strings text in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to implement this(http://web.archive.org/web/20080506155528/http://software.zuavra.net/inline-diff/) with my codeigntier framework but i could not able to implement it. 
Anyone if you have implemented this with codeigniter framework then please help me.

**Why i could not able to implement:**

I run those files seperately(Not with framework) & it worked for me. but while keeping the  same files( i.e `inline_example.php` content) in  my COdeigniter controllers then it showed me too many errors like(shown in image) . Then i though this is out of my capacity to implement with codeignter. so i thought to ask  here help
[image]

Comment: This is old library, using code that is deprecated now. You can either find newer one or disable errors before including/using it and then restore old error reporting level

Comment: @dev-null-dweller   How to find newer one instead of the deprecated on? or How to disable errors before including/using it and then restore old error reporting level?

Answer (score -1):

i have implemented this library in codeigniter.

To resolve that error you have to replace **&new** variable to **new** in all library files of inline diff.

for example :
inline_function.php

```
$diff = &new Text_Diff($hlines1, $hlines2); 

$diff = new Text_Diff($hlines1, $hlines2);
```

and also change path in unified.php and diff.php

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/Text/Diff/Renderer.php');
```